# Update fields only when new value is not None

Tags: python, flask, mongoengine

I want to modify a document based on a PUT request.  However, some of the values in the request are None and end up unsetting values in the document.  How can I update on the fields with values, while leaving the unset fields out?

```
class getUnit(restful.Resource):
    def put(self,unit_id):
        args = parser.parse_args()
        unit = Unit.objects.get_or_404(id=unit_id)
        unit.modify(block_number=args["block_number"], street_name=args["street_name"], postal_code=args["postal_code"], city=args["city"], country=args["country"], coordinates=args["coordinates"], price=args["price"], num_rooms=args["num_rooms"], sqft=args["sqft"])
        return jsonify(result = unit)
```

I tried iterating over each argument but it ends up taking "argument" as a keyword.

```
for argument in arguments:
    if args[argument]:
        unit.modify(argument=args[argument])

return jsonify(result = args[argument])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than setting the values straight from the args, first check if they are not None.

```
def build_modify(args):
    return {key: value for key, value in args if value is not None}
```

Pass the args to this function, unpacking the results into `modify`.

```
unit.modify(**build_modify(parser.parse_args()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write this

```
updated_fields = {'set__'+key:value for key, value in args.items() if value}
unit.update(**updated_fields)
```